# Get id of use element in onclick method of href element

Tags: svg

I have a svg with a simple path element using an onclick callback which is referenced multiple times later:

```
<script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
    function clicked(evt) {
      alert("Id of element: " + evt.IdOfUseElement)
    }
  ]]> </script>


<defs id="defs">
    <path onclick="clicked(evt)" id="BASE" ......></path>
</defs>

......

<use id="use_element_1" xlink:href="#BASE" transform=....../>
<use id="use_element_2" xlink:href="#BASE" transform=....../>
<use id="use_element_3" xlink:href="#BASE" transform=....../>
```

How can I determine in my callback which of the use elements was clicked ? In this example I want to get "use_element_1" or "use_element_3". With evt.id I get the id of the path element ("BASE").

I tried to get the "correspondingElement" from the event but it wasn't successful.

Comment: Instead of using the onclick on the path, use it on the use element

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all the use elements in a `<g>` and add the event listener to that. To make sure that you get one of the use elements you can use `closest()` to find the parent/self.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
    function clicked(evt) {
      let useElm = evt.target.closest('use');
      if(useElm){
        alert("Id of element: " + useElm.id);
      }
    }
  ]]></script>
<defs id="defs">
    <path id="BASE" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" d="M 0 0 h 80"></path>
</defs>
<g onclick="clicked(evt)">
<use id="use_element_1" href="#BASE" transform="translate(10 10)"/>
<use id="use_element_2" href="#BASE" transform="translate(10 20)"/>
<use id="use_element_3" href="#BASE" transform="translate(10 30)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```